# Ajax function never reaching on my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make a plugin with a button which exports to excel a list.

Right now I have the index of the plugin, which shows that list on a table and on top there's the button. This is the code:

The ajax call always returns 0, even if I remove the code and put 'echo "hello" in exportplassere_callback...

```
function exportplassere_callback(){
        require_once  plugins_url('libs/PHPExcel.php', __FILE__);
        global $wpdb;

        $email_list = $wpdb->get_results('
            SELECT email, estado, fecha 
            FROM subscribers 
            ORDER BY fecha');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Prueba')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'Prueba!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Prueba')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'Prueba!');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Prueba');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Prueba"'); //nombre del archivo que se descarga
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }

function altimea_export_page() {
        global $wpdb;
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_exportplassere', 'exportplassere_callback' );

        $email_list = $wpdb->get_results('
            SELECT email, estado, fecha 
            FROM subscribers 
            ORDER BY fecha');
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="header col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <h3>Exportar suscriptores - Plassere</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <form id="ajax_form" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">EXPORTAR</button>
                    </form>
                        <table data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="fecha" data-sort-order="desc">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-sortable="true">Email</th>
                                    <th data-sortable="true">Fecha</th>
                                    <th data-sortable="true">Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($email_list as $suscriber) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $suscriber->email; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($suscriber->fecha)); ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $suscriber->estado; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#ajax_form').bind('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var data = {
                    'action': 'exportplassere',
                    'value': 'prueba'
                };
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);           
                });
            });
        });

        </script>

    <?php } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use ajax in Wordpress you should always state die() at the end of your `function 'or the action'` that returns the ajax data. If you don't state `die();` a `0` will be sent as output back to your script.

This is why the ajax call is always returning a `0`, even  if you echo some kind of string like `hello`.

So in your case you should state `die();` at the end of your action, `exportplassere_callback`, the function that returns your ajax data.

You need to state `die();` just after `$objWriter->save('php://output');` like so:

```
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    die();
}
```